# how to save data permanently without using commit in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, transactions

How can I persist the outcome of a DML statement without executing a COMMIT?  For instance, how can I make this update permanent?

```
     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20

SQL> update emp set comm=200 where empno=7369;


1 row updated.

SQL> select * from emp;
     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800       200          20
```

Comment: The question doesn't make sense.  Databases are fundamentally transactional in nature.  You have to either `commit` or `rollback` any change.  Why don't you want to `commit` your change?

Comment: Committing *is* how we save data.  You might as well ask how to take a shower without getting wet.

Answer (score 1):

In SQLPlus, you can turn autocommit on, and then you don't need to commit manually each transaction:

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT ON
```

You can also use any DDL (data definition language) statement instead of COMMIT,
 since all DDL satements issues implicit commit.
For example, you can use COMMENT statement to commit changes:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE emp IS 'some comment';
```

Answer (score 1):

Committing is how we save changes to a database.  It is not possible to save data to a database without issuing a commit.  The issuing of `commit` (and `rollback`) is what defines a transaction.

Some database clients will allow us to save our changes without explicitly executing a `commit;` statement, by providing an `autocommit` mode.  For instance this is the default behaviour for JDBC [(find out more)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) and ODBC ([find out more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms131281.aspx)).

With SQL*Plus (and most other database IDEs) the default is for manual control of transaction.  But we can cede control by setting `autocommit` to `ON`, `IMMEDIATE` or a numeric value e.g. `SET AUTOCOMMIT 8` will issue a `commit` after every eight DML statements.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_four.htm#SQPUG405).

Running with `autocommit` mode is generally a bad idea.  It is useful to be able to roll back changes just because sometimes we make mistakes. But from a business perspective many transactions comprise more than one DML statement: committing after each one can introduce data corruption, not least because it compromises the Read Committed isolation level.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm#CNCPT1319).

It short, developers should learn to use transactions properly.  It's the key to building reliable database applications.